# No ServiceLocatorGenerator installed Error while Running Tests in Dropwizard

Tags: jersey, guice, dropwizard, hk2

I have upgraded Dropwizard in my project and facing issue while running unit tests, although service start up works fine and all APIs are behaving normally, problem is coming only while running tests, here are my versions:

```
Dropwizard: 1.1.0
Jersey: 2.25.1
Guice: 4.1.0
hk2-api: 2.5.0-b36
hk2-utils: 2.5.0-b36
javax.ws.rs-api : 2.1-m05
```

below is the error when I am running "mvn test"

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It appears there is no ServiceLocatorGenerator installed.
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:153)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:121)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.newInstance(Response.java:848)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:590)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:601)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok(Response.java:622)
...... ** some more lines here **
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It appears there is no ServiceLocatorGenerator installed.
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:123)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:226)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:137)
```

Comment: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1772 and https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice/issues/95 - Seems like some dependencies integration problem.

Comment: Actually there is a pull request pending at `jersey2-guice` project which should resolve the problem. See this comment: https://github.com/Squarespace/jersey2-guice/pull/39#issuecomment-274853295

Answer (score 3):

Calling `JerseyGuiceUtils` before running tests or app can help.

```
static {
    JerseyGuiceUtils.install((s, serviceLocator) -> null);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1772

Answer (score 1):

Looks like incompatible versions Hk2 version.

Please refer to

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1772

for more details.